# Python 8 puzzle BFS infinite loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve the 8 puzzle problem using BFS search, however, my code seems to get stuck in an infinite loop where it only moves the zero tile back and forth until the memory of the queue ends the program in an error.

```
import collections
import queue

class Node:

def __init__(self, puzzle, last=None):
        self.puzzle = puzzle
        self.last = last

    @property
    def seq(self): # to keep track of the sequence used to get to the goal
        node, seq = self, []
        while node:
            seq.append(node)
            node = node.last
        yield from reversed(seq)

    @property
    def state(self):
        return str(self) # hashable so it can be compared in sets

    @property
    def isSolved(self):
        return self.puzzle.isSolved

    @property
    def getMoves(self):
        return self.puzzle.getMoves

class Puzzle:

    def __init__(self, startBoard):
        self.board = startBoard

    @property
    def getMoves(self):

        possibleNewBoards = []

        zeroPos = self.board.index(0) # find the zero tile to determine possible moves

        if zeroPos == 0:
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(0,1))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(0,3))
        elif zeroPos == 1:
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(1,0))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(1,2))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(1,4))
        elif zeroPos == 2:
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(2,1))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(2,5))
        elif zeroPos == 3:
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(3,0))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(3,4))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(3,6))
        elif zeroPos == 4:
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(4,1))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(4,3))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(4,5))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(4,7))
        elif zeroPos == 5:
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(5,2))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(5,4))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(5,8))
        elif zeroPos == 6:
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(6,3))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(6,7))
        elif zeroPos == 7:
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(7,4))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(7,6))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(7,8))
        else:
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(8,5))
            possibleNewBoards.append(self.move(8,7))

        return possibleNewBoards # returns Puzzle objects (maximum of 4 at a time)

    def move(self, current, to):

        changeBoard = self.board[:] # create a copy
        changeBoard[to], changeBoard[current] = changeBoard[current], changeBoard[to] # switch the tiles at the passed positions
        return Puzzle(changeBoard) # return a new Puzzle object

    def printPuzzle(self): # prints board in 8 puzzle style

        copyBoard = self.board[:]
        for i in range(9):
            if i == 2 or i == 5:
                print((str)(copyBoard[i]))
            else:
                print((str)(copyBoard[i])+" ", end="")
        print('\n')

    @property
    def isSolved(self):
        return self.board == [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] # goal board

class Solver:

    def __init__(self, Puzzle):
        self.puzzle = Puzzle

    def solveBFS(self):
        startNode = Node(self.puzzle)
        myQueue = collections.deque([startNode])
        visited = set()
        visited.add(myQueue[0].state)
        while myQueue:
            currentNode = myQueue.pop()
            # currentNode.puzzle.printPuzzle() # used for testing
            if currentNode.puzzle.isSolved:
                return currentNode.seq

            for board in currentNode.getMoves:
                nextNode = Node(board, currentNode)

                if nextNode.state not in visited:
                    myQueue.appendleft(nextNode)
                    visited.add(nextNode.state)

startingBoard = [7,2,4,5,0,6,8,3,1]

myPuzzle = Puzzle(startingBoard)
mySolver = Solver(myPuzzle)
goalSeq = mySolver.solveBFS()

counter = -1 # starting state doesn't count as a move
for node in goalSeq:
    counter = counter + 1
    node.puzzle.printPuzzle()
print("Total number of moves: " + counter)
```

I thought adding each node to a `set()` would stop the code from getting caught in a loop. Is this not true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@property
def state(self):
    return str(self) # hashable so it can be compared in sets
```

This will return something that looks like `<__main__.Node object at 0x02173A90>`. The address is unique per Node object, so the `state` of two nodes with identical boards will still be considered distinct by the set.

Instead, try:

```
@property
def state(self):
    return str(self.puzzle.board)
```

Now two Nodes with identical boards will be considered the same.

Also, change the last line of your script to

```
print("Total number of moves: " + str(counter))
```

Now you will get a result:

```
7 2 4
5 0 6
8 3 1

7 2 4
0 5 6
8 3 1

(snip)

1 0 2
3 4 5
6 7 8

0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8

Total number of moves: 26
```